# NSString to NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I want to split an `NSString` into an `NSArray`. For example, given:

```
NSString *myString=@"ABCDEF";
```

I want an `NSArray` like:

```
NSArray *myArray={A,B,C,D,E,F};
```

How to do this with Objective-C and Cocoa?

Comment: How do you want to handle surrogate pairs and characters composed of to UTF-16 chars?

Answer (score 25):

```
NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *letters = @"ABCDEFक्";
[letters enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [letters length]) 
                            options:(NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences) 
                         usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [letterArray addObject:substring];
}];

for (NSString *i in letterArray){
    NSLog(@"%@",i);
}
```

results in

```
A
B
C
D
E
F

क्
```

`enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` <sub>available for iOS 4+</sub> can enumerate a string with different styles. One is called `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences`, what will enumerate letter by letter but is sensitive to *surrogate pairs, base characters plus combining marks, Hangul jamo, and Indic consonant clusters*, all referred as *Composed Character*

Note, that the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6579795/106435) "swallows" and breaks `क्` into `क` and `्`.

Comment: Definitely the correct way. I made a category out of it: https://gist.github.com/4634479

Comment: In Swift this now takes only one line. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44675708/364446

Answer (score 12):

**Conversion**

```
NSString * string = @"A B C D E F";
NSArray * array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
//Notice that in this case I separated the objects by a space because that's the way they are separated in the string
```

**Logging**

```
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

---

[image: Console]

*This is what the console returned*

Comment: How about this, if you have NSString *myString=@"ABCDEF"; **without space** ??

Comment: You need something to separate it by.

Comment: Otherwise you could use a 'For Loop' and substring the characters into Strings.

Comment: Okay, as per the **Yan.Kun**'s answer

Answer (score 11):

```
NSMutableArray *chars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[theString length]];
for (int i=0; i < [theString length]; i++) {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [theString characterAtIndex:i]];
    [chars addObject:ichar];
}
```

Comment: This is a naïve solution that doesn't handle surrogate pairs or composed characters, as @JeremyP astutely brought up in his comment on the question. Also, don't forget to release the array when not using GC or ARC.

Answer (score 4):

[This link](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Strings/split.html) contains examples to split a string into a array based on sub strings and also based on strings in a character set. I hope that post may help you.

here is the code snip

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myString length]];
for (int i=0; i < [myString length]; i++) {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [myString characterAtIndex:i]];
    [characters addObject:ichar];
}
```

Comment: Consider improving your post since your answer is essentially a link. See: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/156620) and [Why is linking bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/156620)

Comment: @Bavarious, Is that enough? ;-)

Comment: @Bavarious agree, The answer having only link are no more useful once URL goes dead. So **EmptyStack** please!  try to post some code that may help in future for anyone. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Without loop you can use this:

```
NSString *myString = @"ABCDEF";
NSMutableString *tempStr =[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:myString];

if([myString length] != 0)
{
    NSError  *error  = NULL;

    // declare regular expression object
    NSRegularExpression *regex =[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.)" options:NSMatchingReportCompletion error:&error];

    // replace each match with matches character + <space> e.g. 'A' with 'A '
    [regex replaceMatchesInString:tempStr options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0,[myString length]) withTemplate:@"$0 "];

    // trim last <space> character
    [tempStr replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([tempStr length] - 1, 1) withString:@""];

    // split into array
    NSArray * arr = [tempStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    // print
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
}
```

This solution append space in front of each character with the help of regular expression and uses `componentsSeparatedByString` with `<space>` to return an array

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2:**

**String to Array**

```
let list = "Karin, Carrie, David"

let listItems = list.components(separatedBy: ", ")
```

Output : ["Karin", "Carrie", "David"]

**Array to String**

```
let list = ["Karin", "Carrie", "David"]

let listStr = list.joined(separator: ", ")
```

Output : "Karin, Carrie, David"

Answer (score -1):

In Swift, this becomes very simple.

Swift 3:

```
myString.characters.map { String($0) }
```

Swift 4:

```
myString.map { String($0) }
```