# separating strings by -

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring

I have a string "hai-welcome".

I need to split the above string using '-' separator:

mySstring = "hai-welcome"
Separate as:

firstString  = "hai"
secondString = "welcome.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304450/split-nsstring-into-nsarray      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579728/nsstring-to-nsarray

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this by using "componentsSeparatedByString" method of NSString.

```
NSString * source =  @"hai-welcome";
NSArray * stringArray = [source componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSString * firstPart = [stringArray objectAtIndex:0]; // Contains string "hai"
NSString * secondPart =[stringArray objectAtIndex:1]; //Contans string "welcome"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use NSString's componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet method

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Strings/split.html

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray* foo = [@"hai-welcome" componentsSeparatedByString: @"-"];
NSString* first = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString* second = [foo objectAtIndex: 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
NSString *str = @"hai-welcome";
NSArray *listItems = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to work with other than `componentsSeparatedByString` function, I would offer this solution to adopt:

```
NSString *myString =  @"hai-welcome";
NSString *firstString = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [myString rangeOfString:@"-"].location)];
NSString *secondString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[firstString stringByAppendingString:@"-"] withString:@""];
```