# Parse html NSString with REGEX

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, regex

I have `NSString` with couple strings like this that the `465544664646` is change between them :

```
data-context-item-title="465544664646"
```

How i parse the `465544664646` string to a Array ?

Edit

```
NSRegularExpression* myRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(?i)(data-context-item-title=\")(.+?)(\")" options:0 error:nil];
[myRegex enumerateMatchesInString:responseString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [responseString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *string =[responseString substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(string);
}];
```

Comment: i found some ways to do it but i success only one string but not all of them

Comment: What is your string? is it `data-context-item-title="465544664646"` and you want to extract `465544664646` and store it in array?

Comment: @MTA, even if the code doesn't work, still show it please!

Comment: I have a big string with a lot of `data-context-item-title="*****"` and i want to get all the *****(can be anything)

Comment: Please provide more information about your string. eg. is it possible that your string contains " anywhere else?

Comment: Mert : no " in the string. and i edit my post too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
NSString *yourString=@"data-context-item-title=\"465544664646\" data-context-item-title=\"1212121212\"";

NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray new];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:nil];
while(![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *tempString;
    [scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:nil];
    if([scanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&tempString]) {
        [substrings addObject:tempString];
    }
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:nil];
}

//NSLog(@"->%@",substrings); //substrings contains all numbers as string.


for (NSString *str in substrings) {
    NSLog(@"->%ld",[str integerValue]); //converted each number to integer value, if you want to store as NSNumber now you can store each of them in array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    -(NSString *)stringFromOriginalString:(NSString *)origin betweenStartString:    (NSString*)start andEndString:(NSString*)end {
    NSRange startRange = [origin rangeOfString:start];
    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange targetRange;
        targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
        targetRange.length = [origin length] - targetRange.location;
        NSRange endRange = [origin rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];
        if (endRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
            return [origin substringWithRange:targetRange];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

method like

```
NSArray *components = [@"data-context-item-title="465544664646" componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
```

Now you should got the string at 2. index

```
[components objectAtIndex:1]
```

Now you can create array from that string using the method here 
[NSString to NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579728/nsstring-to-nsarray)