# Convert NSString to NSArray of characters

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I'm trying to convert NSString to NSArray of characters by I haven't found a way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *one = @"abc";
const char *charOne= [one UTF8String];
```

But if I try to convert NSArray:

```
 NSArray *arrayOne = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray*)charOne];
```

I get this error:
Cast of non-Objective-C pointer type const char * to NSArray is disallowed in ARC

My question to guys, how can I can convert NSString to NSArray of characters?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Clarify what you want in the array. Do you want an array of `unichar`? An array of `NSString` each representing a single character? Note that some Unicode characters won't fit in `unichar`.

Comment: I think this answer help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501898/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-nsarray

Comment: @ShalomDahan, if you look closely the string doesn't have commas

Comment: @Cristik if that is the case why the error?

Comment: @rmaddy, array of substrings (NSString) it would work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *letters = @"ABCDEFक्";
[letters enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [letters length]) 
                                    options:(NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences) 
                                 usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
            [letterArray addObject:substring];
        }];
```

from : [NSString to NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579728/nsstring-to-nsarray)